# Stange behavior :nth-of-type(odd) in table row

Tags: html, html-table, css-selectors, tr

Hi i have table rows with 2 css classes `child` and `parent`. `child` are hidden (display: none) and i want give even/odd colour difference to `parent` classes. But despide my class selector it looks like it not working properly.

```css
table tr.parent:nth-of-type(odd) td {
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="parent">1</td>
    <td>parent</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>none</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>none</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>parent</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent">
    <td>5</td>
    <td>parent</td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="parent">
    <td>5</td>
    <td>parent</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is working fine. Your first parent class is given to td and not tr. Put it on the tr and it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the first parent class to a td and not tr. Remove the first parent class from the td and put it on the tr.

Check my code.

```css
table tr.parent:nth-of-type(odd) td {
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="parent">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>parent</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>none</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>none</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>parent</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent">
    <td>5</td>
    <td>parent</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent">
    <td>5</td>
    <td>parent</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yep! Sorry that's my oversight... It is okay now